# How can I get bundler to use the Ruby version set by chruby and .ruby-version?

Tags: ruby, bundler, chruby

I have the pleasure of setting up a development environment for an application running Ruby 1.8.7. Unfortunately `bundler` is not using the version of Ruby set in `.ruby-version` by `chruby`.

Also, I have `ruby "1.8.7"` included in the `Gemfile`

Whereas the local version is `ruby-1.8.7-p374`, the `bundler` environment is using `ruby-2.5.0p0`.

```
$ ruby -v
ruby 1.8.7 (2013-06-27 patchlevel 374) [i686-darwin17.3.0]

$ bundle env | grep Ruby
Ruby          2.5.0p0 (2017-12-25 revision 61468) [x86_64-darwin17]
```

This results in the following message:

```
$ bundler
Your Ruby version is 2.5.0, but your Gemfile specified 1.8.7
```

[This issue](https://github.com/bundler/bundler/issues/4260) contains some helpful comments but so far I haven't been able to resolve the issue. I do have Ruby 2.5.0 installed in `/usr/local/opt` as a result of installing `vim` via `brew install vim`. This would appear to the version that the Ruby 1.8.7 bundle script is using, as evidenced by:

```
$ which bundle
/Users/keithpitty/.gem/ruby/1.8.7/bin/bundle

$ head -n1 $(which bundle)
#!/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin/ruby
```

This problem is proving to be quite frustrating. I would very much appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: Do you still have this issue? If yes, did you tried re-install Bundler?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I now realise I forgot to provide the solution here. I'll add it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by installing RubyGems 1.6.2. See [How to set correct Ruby version in gem environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48575868/how-to-set-correct-ruby-version-in-gem-environment/48577690#48577690) for more.

Answer (score 0):

Have you mentioned the ruby version in Gemfile you are planning to use, if not trying adding the ruby version in your Gemfile, more info [here](http://bundler.io/v1.12/gemfile_ruby.html).

```
ruby '~> 2.3.0'
```

Also on a side note, if you have multiple ruby versions in you machine, ideally you can make use [RVM](http://rvm.io/) or [rbenv](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv) to manage multiple Ruby versions. ( makes your life easy :) )

Comment: Yes, as already noted, I have specified `ruby "1.8.7"` in the Gemfile and I use `chruby` rather than `rvm` or `rbenv` to manage multiple Ruby versions.

Answer (score 0):

I followed these instructions
https://gist.github.com/andrewroycarter/6815905

In short, I have a project using 2.5.8 and my local version is 2.7.2, so bundle install says

> Your Ruby version is 2.7.2, but your Gemfile specified 2.5.8

What I did was to go to my home directory (or at least leave the project directory), activate chruby 2.5.8 and install the bundle gem

```
cd
chruby 2.5.8
gem install bundler
```

Now, when I go back to the project directory I can do bundle install.