# How to set correct Ruby version in gem environment

Tags: ruby, rubygems, ruby-1.8.7, chruby

Note: This question relates to [How can I get bundler to use the Ruby version set by chruby and .ruby-version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48435360/how-can-i-get-bundler-to-use-the-ruby-version-set-by-chruby-and-ruby-version).

Using `chruby` I have Ruby 1.8.7 installed on macOS:

```
$ ruby -v
ruby 1.8.7 (2013-06-27 patchlevel 374) [i686-darwin17.4.0]
```

Also, I have used `gem update --system 1.8.30` to install a specific version of RubyGems which I am hoping is compatible. This would appear to be installed properly:

```
$ gem --version
1.8.30
```

However, my RubyGems environment shows the incorrect version of Ruby (2.5.0):

```
$ gem env
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.8.30
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.5.0 (2017-12-25 patchlevel 0) [x86_64-darwin17]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/keithpitty/.gem/ruby/1.8.7
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /usr/local/opt/ruby/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /Users/keithpitty/.gem/ruby/1.8.7/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-darwin-17
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /Users/keithpitty/.gem/ruby/1.8.7
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :benchmark => false
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - http://rubygems.org/
```

How can I fix the RubyGems environment to use the version of Ruby that `chruby` has set?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My missing step was installing RubyGems 1.6.2 from source. Following advice elsewhere from [Dan Cheail](https://stackoverflow.com/users/190985/dan-cheail), I did the following:

```
curl -O https://rubygems.org/rubygems/rubygems-1.6.2.tgz
```

(and then unzipped it)

```
cd rubygems-1.6.2
chruby ruby-1.8.7-p374
ruby setup.rb
gem update --system 1.8.25
```

And then my RubyGems environment was fixed:

```
$ gem env
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.8.25
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.8.7 (2013-06-27 patchlevel 374) [i686-darwin17.4.0]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/keithpitty/.gem/ruby/1.8.7
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /Users/keithpitty/.rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p374/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /Users/keithpitty/.gem/ruby/1.8.7/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86-darwin-17
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /Users/keithpitty/.gem/ruby/1.8.7
     - /Users/keithpitty/.rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p374/lib/ruby/gems/1.8
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :benchmark => false
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - http://rubygems.org/
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a Ruby Version Manager such as (chruby)[https://github.com/postmodern/chruby] and you have auto-switching enabled. Check the .ruby-version file and if it doesn't exist, add one with the version number you require, for example

`echo "2.7.8" > .ruby-version`

Then check your `gem env` again.